# HTTPS Proxy website to create a fake site

Tags: http, networking, https, proxy, protocols

Okay, so I have coded allot with proxys including creating a "fake" website with HTTP, in other words I made my proxy forward any domain with ".example" extension to a local file. I would like to do the same with HTTPS, however I'm unsure if I would need to have a certificate for every domain or even need one at all. If I end up needing a certificate can I self sign it without the browser questioning the legitimacy of it?

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can place all "fake" domains behind cloudflare.com and use their SSL certificate. To make settings simpler you can self sign SSL for each domain

Comment: Thats not a bad idea, I ended up just creating a root cert on my machine and self signing all certs from there.